# Members/Users - Should we not standardise these terms within StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

There seems to be two terms used for visitors of StackExchange websites, and considering the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), there is the following:

> **No bigotry.**
> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.

Now, to be clear (*"Be inclusive and respectful."* because *"tone is hard to decipher online"*) I don't consider anyone here to be bigoted, but I wish to ask the question on whether we are website users (see the left column of this page under the [Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) link) or members of a StackExchange community (see any person's profile page — mine for example states "Member for 3 years, 1 month" for this site and "Member for 5 years" for Psychology.SE)?

Speaking from a psychological standpoint, the term **user** can have many different connotations and I wonder whether the term should be moderated in use, if used at all.

For example, a website **user** could have the connotation that the person is just visiting the site to get what they can out of it and dumping it. Whilst this may be true for a small minority of StackExchange visitors, the majority are more than that in my mind.

Are we not **members of a StackExchange community** who contribute to the continuance of StackExchange? After-all, without the communities within all the SE sites, there would be no StackExchange — not in the format it is now.

Comment: We are both members AND users, the fact we joined makes us members and the making use of the site makes us users, they are not mutually exclusive terms. Please just stop with the language policing, there is nothing wrong with the term user unless you go looking for one.

Comment: What does the first part of this question have to do with the second? What is *"likely to offend or alienate"* or bigoted about *either* of those terms? FWIW plenty of visitors to SE sites, with or without accounts, *are* *"just visiting the site to get what they can out of it"*, and as long as they are still following the rules that's absolutely fine.

Comment: "For example, a website user could have the connotation that the person is just visiting the site to get what they can out of it and dumping it." If we're here to help people (which is exactly what I intended), why the negative language when someone gets a question they had answered and goes about with their own lives?

Comment: Member or a community doesn't really mean anything if the community isn't really defined. I would first try to define what the community really is - I have no idea really. We interact here on a daily basis, but I feel like an individual. I do what I think is right within the boundaries of the software and I know that I can walk away any time. So what does this make me?

Comment: I think you have it backwards.  The tremendous majority of people that get information here probably never go beyond a click to a target provided by their search engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term *user* is perfect from all points of views.

1. It is magnificently gender neutral. It is blind to age, skin colour, and creed.
2. It describes what the person does: they *use* a product or service.
3. It is a very short easy-to-pronounce word and as such rarely misspelt (*misspelled* for those who are more familiar with American English.)
4. It is perhaps the most common term to denote any person, either expert or novice,  who participates on a website; purchases an app, or operates a programme.
5. We typically associate the adjectives ***regular***,  ***avid***, ***frequent*** and ***heavy*** with "user". Only the last adjective carries negative and possibly derogatory connotations.
6. And finally, the term is thoroughly entrenched in the English language for example:   ***computer / internet / mobile phone / business / home users*** and we speak about ***user manuals***, ***user-friendly*** and ***user-interface***.

Answer (score 4):

I like the term "users" in the sidebar: "users" is standard computer jargon, to refer to "people" (as opposed to e.g. "questions", "tags", etc).

And "Members" sounds like an exclusive club ("members only"), though OK in the right context.

Comment: In Russian computer jargon, the word 'user' means "not a programmer." This word can be considered pejorative.

Comment: I think anglophone programmers know that they themselves are computer users too. Also there is a separate word of old (obsolete) programmer's jargon to use if you wanted to try to be pejorative, or needed to unambiguously use a more pejorative word -- "[luser](http://catb.org/jargon/html/L/luser.html)".